# Prevent UIViewControllerRepresentable from updating

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I'm following the [Interfacing with UIKit tutorial from the SwiftUI website](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit), and I'm implementing my own `PageViewController` inside my app. For now, it shares the same code as the tutorial.

The problem is that one of the `controllers` I'm passing inside `PageViewController`, has a `Button` that changes the `State` of the container.

This is the `Container`

```swift
@State private var counter: Int
@State private var currentPage: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        PageViewController(
            controllers: [UIHostingController(rootView: Page(counter: self.$counter))], 
            currentPage: self.$currentPage
        )
    }
}
```

and `Page` is like

```swift
struct Page: some View {

    @Binding counter: Int

    var body: some View {
        Button(
            action: {
                self.counter +=1
            }
        ){
             Text("Increase counter")
        }
        Text("Value: \(self.counter)")
    }
}
```

Whenever I press the `Button`, the counter increases, the `State` gets updated, and the `updateUIViewController` inside the `PageViewController` struct gets triggered.

The update does this

```swift
func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
   pageViewController.setViewControllers([sItemsControllers[self.currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)   
}
```

So everytime the `updateUIViewController` is triggered, the `PageViewController` gets updated, and the next Page is presented.

Any suggestion on how can I prevent it?

Comment: Isn’t that expected behaviour?

Comment: What is `currentItemIndex`? There is code missing which makes it unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to declare the page with the counter and make the page appear there? Having a currentItemIndex besides the counter means you have two state variables which are supposed to control the page. If you want to synchronize them you can jump there directly (if the page controller permits) or go the appropriate steps forward or backward to get there.

Comment: @Fabian currentItemIndex was a mistake, I've corrected it with currentPage. I'm omitting the full `PageViewController` class because it is the same as the tutorial in the link. What I want to do is avoid the pageViewController to update itself (and thus changing page with an animation) whenever I press the `Button` inside it. The `Button` doesn't change `currentPage`, but the animation is still executed because the `updateUIMake` fires. I don't know how to explain this better, but I'd like to do it like Flutter where a `setState()` inside a `PageView` doesn't automatically reload the view.

Comment: I meant `updateUIViewController` sorry

Comment: You can't stop state-changes from calling `updateUIViewController` since that method has that sole purpose. (Changing @State-variables, @Published variables and calling `objectWillChange.send()` do that). What you can do is hide the `setViewControllers` method behind an if like `if counter == x { // Update }`. Was that what you ment?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there was a better solution...it seems hacky